# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) , when I try to extract only 2 substrings from a regex pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, regex-group

This is the code but the part of the error is where is the extraction of the substrings after validating the regex pattern structure

```py
def name_and_img_identificator(input_text, text):
    input_text = re.sub(r"([^n\u0300-\u036f]|n(?!\u0303(?![\u0300-\u036f])))[\u0300-\u036f]+", r"\1", normalize("NFD", input_text), 0, re.I)
    input_text = normalize( 'NFC', input_text) # -> NFC
    input_text_to_check = input_text.lower() #Convierte a minuscula todo

    
    #regex_patron_01 = r"\s*\¿?(?:dime los|dime las|dime unos|dime unas|dime|di|cuales son los|cuales son las|cuales son|cuales|que animes|que|top)\s*((?:\w+\s*)+)\s*(?:de series anime|de anime series|de animes|de anime|animes|anime)\s*(?:similares al|similares a|similar al|similar a|parecidos al|parecidos a|parecido al|parecido a)\s*(?:la serie de anime|series de anime|la serie anime|la serie|anime|)\s*(llamada|conocida como|cuyo nombre es|la cual se llama|)\s*((?:\w+\s*)+)\s*\??"

    #Regex in english
    regex_patron_01 = r "\ s * \ ¿? (?: tell me the | tell me some| tell me | say | which are the | which are the | which are | which | which animes | which | top) \ s * ((?: \ w + \ s *) +) \ s * (?: anime series | anime series | anime | anime | anime | anime) \ s * (?: similar to | similar to | similar to | similar to | similar to | similar to | similar to | similar to) \ s * (?: the anime series | anime series | the anime series | the series | anime |) \ s * (called | known like | whose name is | which is called |) \ s * ((?: \ w + \ s *) +) \ s * \ ?? "

    m = re.search(regex_patron_01, input_text_to_check, re.IGNORECASE) #Con esto valido la regex haber si entra o no en el bloque de code

    if m:
        num, anime_name = m.groups()[2]

        num = num.strip()
        anime_name = anime_name.strip()
        print(num)
        print(anime_name)

    return text

input_text_str = input("ingrese: ")
text = ""

print(name_and_img_identificator(input_text_str, text))
```

It gives me this error, and the truth is I don't know how to structure this regex pattern so that it only extracts those 2 values (substrings) from that input

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "serie_recommendarion_for_chatbot.py", line 154, in <module>
    print(serie_and_img_identificator(input_text_str, text))
  File "anime_recommendarion_for_chatbot.py", line 142, in name_and_img_identificator
    num, anime_name = m.groups()
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

If I put an input like this:
'Dame el top 8 de animes parecidos a Gundam'
'Give me the top 8 anime like Gundam'

I need you to extract:

```py
num = '8'
anime_name = 'Gundam'
```

How do I have to fix my regex sequence in that case?

Comment: This is missing imports: `import re` and `from unicodedata import normalize`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Errors in the regex pattern

1. You forgot to add `?:` to not capture this group. Change:

```
regex_patron_01 = r"...(llamada|conocida como|cuyo nombre es|la cual se llama|)..."
```

To:

```
regex_patron_01 = r"...(?:llamada|conocida como|cuyo nombre es|la cual se llama|)..."
```

2. To not capture additional spaces or words, your capturing of the `num` should be non-greedy so that it doesn't catch words like `"de"`and let the succeeding patterns match it. Change:

```
regex_patron_01 = r"...((?:\w+\s*)+)..."
```

To:

```
regex_patron_01 = r"...((?:\w+?\s*?)+)..."
```

3. The `.groups()` contain already the string matches, thus accessing an index would give you a single string only, which is the root cause of your error. Change:

```
num, anime_name = m.groups()[2]
```

To:

```
num, anime_name = m.groups()
```

With those changes above, it would be successful:

```
8
gundam
```

#### Improvement

Your regex is too complicated and contains a lot of hard-coded words which would differ by language. My suggestion is to set a standard on the format of the string it can accept to:

```
Any text here (num) any text here (anime_name)
```

Which is already the format of your input:

```
Dame el top 8 de animes parecidos a Gundam
```

Thus you can remove that long regex and replace with this and the output would be the same:

```
regex_patron_01 = r"^.*?(\d+).*\s(.+)$"
```

Note that this requires the `(anime_name)` to be a single-word. To support multi-words, we have to set a special character that will mark the start of the anime name such as colon `:`

```
Dame el top 8 de animes parecidos a: Gundam X
```

Then the regex would be:

```
regex_patron_01 = r"^.*?(\d+).*:\s(.+)$"
```

**Output**

```
8
gundam x
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try extracting the first 2 values, maybe you are missing a colon.

```py
num, anime_name = m.groups()[:2]
```

That might be the case because you are facing the `too many values to unpack` error.

---

Use two separate patterns for the number and the name. For simplicity, I only included a few examples.

**For the number** [Test cases](https://regexr.com/660cf)

```
(?<=(which are the|which|top)\s)[0-9]+(?=\s(anime series|anime))
```

**For the name** [Test cases](https://regexr.com/660ci)

```
(?<=(like|called|which is called)\s)[A-Za-z]+
```

The rest is your job to implement the patterns in Spanish.

Comment: I was trying that but I have num = '8' and anime_name = ''.
But I need num = '8' and anime_name = 'Gundam'

Comment: @ElectrisikVocal Ok, now the error is solved. Let's have a look at your regex.

Comment: @ElectrisikVocal Sorry, I don't know Spanish very well but I suggest you not to use regular expressions to solve linguistic problems because there are a lot of cases and irregularities in languages. You can use other hints like capital letters, for example, capital G in Gundam. Or a better way is to use NLP, but that is a bit too complicated for your use case.

Comment: in this case I only want to extract the strings that would remain in the places where I put in this case I only want to extract the strings that would remain in the places where I put ((?: \ w + \ s *) +)

Comment: In the regex pattern you will only see that it can 2 times that sequence which are the 2 places where it is supposed to extract the substrings

Comment: @ElectrisikVocal Try using two separate regex patterns for the number and the name. Again, I can't help you on this because I don't know Spanish very well, but [lookahead and lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2973436/16936415) are what you need for this.

Comment: I have already edited my question and created the regex equivalent in English, it still crashes anyway, maybe you can think of something to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out in the Regex playground: [Link](https://regex101.com/r/YcH4gd/1)

So nothing much is changed, the first capture group is still the quantifier for the number of animes, and the 2nd group is the name of the anime itself. I just simplified the regex a bit (got rid of some unnecessary bits for demo purposes). Most of it is unchanged from your version, which was actually pretty solid regex.

Regex: `\b(\d+).*(?:called|that are like|known like|whose name is|which is called)\s*((?:\w+\s*)+)\s*\??`

---

Test with your original question - which I translated roughly to English :-)

```py
import re
from unicodedata import normalize


def name_and_img_identificator(input_text, text):
    input_text = re.sub(r"([^n\u0300-\u036f]|n(?!\u0303(?![\u0300-\u036f])))[\u0300-\u036f]+", r"\1",
                        normalize("NFD", input_text), 0, re.I)
    input_text = normalize('NFC', input_text)  # -> NFC
    input_text_to_check = input_text.lower()  # Convierte a minuscula todo


    # Regex in english

    # original
    #   note: you have extra spaces here, which regex might not like.
    #   you can get rid of spaces and then it should hopefully be fine.
    # regex_patron_01 = r "\ s * \ ¿? (?: tell me the | tell me some| tell me | say | which are the | which are the | which are | which | which animes | which | top) \ s * ((?: \ w + \ s *) +) \ s * (?: anime series | anime series | anime | anime | anime | anime) \ s * (?: similar to | similar to | similar to | similar to | similar to | similar to | similar to | similar to) \ s * (?: the anime series | anime series | the anime series | the series | anime |) \ s * (called | known like | whose name is | which is called |) \ s * ((?: \ w + \ s *) +) \ s * \ ?? "

    # simplified
    regex_patron_01 = r'\b(\d+).*(?:called|that are like|known like|whose name is|which is called)\s*((?:\w+\s*)+)\s*\??'

    m = re.search(regex_patron_01, input_text_to_check,
                  re.IGNORECASE)  # Con esto valido la regex haber si entra o no en el bloque de code

    if m:
        num, anime_name = m.groups()[:2]

        num = num.strip()
        anime_name = anime_name.strip()
        print(num)
        print(anime_name)

    return text


#input_text_str = input("ingrese: ")
input_text_str = 'Tell me the top 8 animes that are like Gundam?'
text = ""

print(name_and_img_identificator(input_text_str, text))
```

Comment: no problem! hope a part of it was helpful at least :-)